# REST API Create Multiple Records

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest

Create multiple records with reference to the official documentation:[Create multiple documentation url](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm)
[image]

But I need to fill the lookup field value, I found the official document again：[update documentation url](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm)
[image]

I find that I cannot use them at the same time.
Finally I found [Execute Dependent Requests in a Single API Call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_record_manipulation.htm)
[image]
Although I got the result I finally wanted, unfortunately: **Composite Resources** only supports 25 sub-requests, and my Account has a lot of lookup fields, and needs to support List because I worry about exceeding the **24 hour API request limit**. I know that I can use APEX to complete my function,I want to try using standard REST to accomplish it. Does anyone give me a good suggestion?

Comment: The 24 hour API request limit is generally _very high_. What is your data volume?

Comment: @DavidReed  ORG API Requests（Last 24 Hours） : 35,000 max ,The customer data reaches about 4 million, and there are about 10,000 customer requests per day, and there are other object requests.